# I'm 5 weeks pregnant from unlawful relationship, should I abort ?!

Tags: halal-haram, sex

I am a revert to Islam. I have sinned as I meet a non practicing muslim man and have been seeing him on and off for the last 2 and a half years. We have spoken about marriage, thou due to his family circumstances he has never mentioned me to them and stated "in time will come." I had not seen not him for over 6 months then I had travelled to see him and had intercourse, 2 days later I had taken the morning after pill..

I have just recently found out that I am 5 weeks pregnant and am very confused of what to do. I have many years ago went through an abortion with my previous  marriage and promised Allah (swt) I would never do it again and to please forgive me. I am now in this situation where I feel I need to keep it and the father of the unborn child is saying I should abort it. I have sinned and I feel I now am being punished with the situation I have been put in. The father has stated if I abort the unborn that will donut the right way and get married, then have children. I need help with the right guidance of what I should do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Relationships according to Quran](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8185/relationships-according-to-quran)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some scholars are of the opinion that it's permissible to abort a fetus before it's 120 days old (see [Is abortion permitted in Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/927/is-abortion-permitted-in-islam#answer-936)), which is the case with regards to your own pregnancy. You may not marry this man until both of you make sincere repentance to God, as it is forbidden in Islam to knowingly marry an adulterer (see [Marrying an Adulterer](http://islamqa.info/en/85335)). However, I do have concerns about the path you're following. If you do go ahead and abort the child, it will be your second abortion, which could be bad for your health. Secondly, from the description you've given of this man, I'm not too sure whether you're making the right decision to marry him, as you said, he's a non-practising Muslim and he seems reluctant to marry you for some reason. It is forbidden for you to continue being alone with this man and living with him without being married. I do think you need to surround yourself with pious Muslims which could protect you from falling into similar situations in the future. Please do also learn how to offer the [Istikhaarah prayer](http://islamqa.info/en/11981).

Answer (score 2):

**"At the time of Prophet Muhammed(pbuh) a woman came to him and said she was into a bad relationship(without marriage) and asked for the punishment (Punishment for Prostitute or bad relationship is throwing stone upon the victim to Death). Prophet Muhammed(pbuh) asked was she pregnant and the woman said yes.
So, Prophet Muhammed(pbuh) said gave birth to the child and then come to me( birth time is ~10 months).
The woman came to Prophet Muhammed(pbuh) after given birth to the child she carried.
Then Prophet Muhammed(pbuh) asked who was she? and the woman said the things.
Then Prophet Muhammed(pbuh) asked come after when the child forget milk feeding (milk feeding is 2 yrs).
After 2 yrs the woman again came to Prophet Muhammed(pbuh) and told that the child had forgotten milk feeding.
Then Prophet Muhammed(pbuh) called all Shahaabahs and told them to punish that woman to death(the punishment is throwing stones till death).
And one Shahaabah scolded that woman for that bad relationship, then Prophet Muhammed(pbuh) said don't scold her  and said she will stand purely without any sin in front of Allah in after life."**

sorry i don't remember the Hadith number but it is a Hadith.

By this Hadith, the woman was pregnant because of bad relation ( without marriage) and Prophet Muhammed(pbuh) didn't tell her to abort the child, instead he said give birth to that child and grow till he forgets the milk feeding.

so you should not abort the child.
you should grow that child.
but if you want to be without sin. you have to accept the punishment for the bad relationship in your country or pray to Allah to forgive your great sin.

Ya Allah, Please forgive this sister's sin and help her to raise the child in a good manner.

Comment: https://sunnah.com/search/?q=birth+zina

Answer (score 0):

First of all realize I have no reason to judge you or your choices, I can only give you the answer I can.

You said you went through abortion already and you clearly said you gave your promise to Allah that you won't do it again.

Maybe you didn't read Qur'an but for every Muslim a promise shouldn't be taken lightly or given lightly.
Every broken promise is haram.
( your promise was given to Allah so be strong and keep it)

But promise aside, you made a mistake and Allah knows if you regret it.
In the Holy Qur'an it's haram for parents to kill their children.
That alone maybe won't be enough for you to decide to keep that baby.
Your partner has the right to know you're pregnant because in the Holy Qur'an it's written that it's haram to keep that information from the father.

You did a mistake, that's neither your first nor your last mistake, but how you handle it will show what kind of a person you are, regardless of what scholars say about abortion, you did give Allah that promise, even if you didn't the abortion shouldn't be on the table at all because it's forbidden. adding another haram thing won't make things better for you in this life and even less in the afterlife.

Allah says he'll test us, this could be your test, even if you hate the situation you're in right now, that baby could be your blessing.

Any decision you make, I'd advise you to talk to that man, I have a feeling his answer and his reaction will tell you a lot about him.
After you see his reaction, you'll see the baby is blessing, the fact you didn't marry him is a blessing too. After all, all decisions are yours, but remember that right or wrong decision will have consequences.

Allah knows best

Answer (score -2):

of course you should not. 1) i think it is prohibited at all; because it is killing an because it is changing what allah made and it is prohibited by quran 4:119; 2) what is "donut"? what he says has no strength since it is prohibited by allah. and why you even believe him?! i think, you should not and need not believe him.