# Can i abort rape child?

Tags: halal-haram, medical, pregnancy, rape

I am a woman in my twenties. I was raped. Since he is an influential person i couldn’t get justice. Now i am pregnant with his child. I want to abort it. I don’t want to bear a rapists child in my womb. Is it permissible?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. For further information about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: We are sorry for what you've experienced.There should be some questions on the topic of abortion on the site. Basically scholars consider this as permissible (mainly) regardless of the reason, expect of the matter of fearing poverty if the child was born. The issue is the timing for this intervention and I think there are some different opinions, however the earlier you do this the less scholars would regard this as haraam.

Comment: Here some related posts: [Is abortion permitted in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/927/is-abortion-permitted-in-islam) and [I'm 5 weeks pregnant from unlawful relationship should I abort?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16186/im-5-weeks-pregnant-from-unlawful-relationship-should-i-abort) I hope this helps! (please let us know).

Comment: Also see [islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/13317/abortion-of-pregnancy-resulting-from-rape)